# this code should print unique vowels in the list?But why is it printing repeated vowels?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
v = ['a','e','i','o','u']
word ="Milliwaysaaa"
found = []
for i in word:
    if i in v:
        if i not in found:
            print(i)
```

This should print only the *unique* vowels, but it prints them all.  Why?

Comment: When would anything ever be in `found`?

Comment: `found` is always an empty list.

Comment: You forgot to update `found`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set()` operations, this will print elements common to the vowels and word:

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
word ="Milliwaysaaa"

print(set(vowels) & set(word))
```

Prints:

```
{'i', 'a'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `found` when you encounter a new vowel.
Add that line:

```
v = ['a','e','i','o','u']
word ="Milliwaysaaa"
found = []
for i in word:
    if i in v:
        if i not in found:
            print(i)
            found.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're not adding anything to the `found` list at any point, which means it always remains empty.

Try adding `found.append(i)` after your print statement.

Also, here's a more concise way to achieve what you want:

```
v = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
word = "Milliwaysaaa"

found = set(filter(lambda i: i in v, word))

print(found)
```

Output:

```
{'a', 'i'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
v = ['a','e','i','o','u']
word ="Milliwaysaaa"

d=dict(Counter(word))
found=[key for key in d.keys() if key in v]

#['a', 'i']
```